# How can I summarise this JSON array data as columns on the same row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL database with a table called `items` which includes a JSONB field `care_ages`.

This field contains an array of between one and three objects, which include these keys:

- AgeFrom
- AgeTo
- Number
- Register

For a one-off audit report I need to run on this table, I need to "unpack" this field into columns on the same row.

I've used `jsonb_to_recordset` to split it out into rows and columns, which gets me halfway:

```
SELECT
    items.id,
    items.name,
    care_ages.*

FROM 
    ofsted_items,
    jsonb_to_recordset(items.care_age) AS care_ages ("AgeFrom" integer, "AgeTo" integer, "Register" text, "MaximumNumber" integer)
```

This gives me output like:

```
| id | name         | register | age_from | age_to | maximum_number |
|----|--------------|----------|----------|--------|----------------|
| 1  | namey mcname | xyz      | 0        | 4      | 5              |
| 1  | namey mcname | abc      | 4        | 8      | 7              |
```

Next, I need to combine these rows together, perhaps using `GROUP BY`, adding extra columns, like this:

```
| id | name         | register_xyz? | xyz_age_from | xyz_age_to | xyz_maximum_number | register_abc? | abc_age_from | abc_age_to | abc_maximum_number |
|----|--------------|---------------|--------------|------------|--------------------|---------------|--------------|------------|--------------------|
| 1  | namey mcname | true          | 0            | 4          | 5                  | true          | 4            | 8          | 7                  |
```

Because I know ahead of time which "registers" there are (there's only three of them), it seems like this should be possible.

I've tried following [this example](https://ubiq.co/database-blog/create-pivot-table-postgresql/), using `CASE` to calculate extra columns, but I'm not getting any useful values: all 0s and 5s for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Postgres 12 or later, you can use a jsonpath query to first extract the JSON object for each register into separate columns. Then use the "usualy" operators to extract the keys. This avoids first expanding into multiple rows just to aggregate them back into a single row later

```
select id, name, 
        (reg_xyz ->> 'AgeFrom')::int as xyz_age_from,
        (reg_xyz ->> 'AgeTo')::int as xyz_age_to,
        (reg_xyz ->> 'Number')::int as xyz_max_num,
        (reg_abc ->> 'AgeFrom')::int as abc_age_from,        
        (reg_abc ->> 'AgeTo')::int as abc_age_to,
        (reg_abc ->> 'Number')::int as abc_max_num
from (        
  select id, name, 
         jsonb_path_query_first(care_age, '$[*] ? (@.Register == "xyz")') as reg_xyz,
         jsonb_path_query_first(care_age, '$[*] ? (@.Register == "abc")') as reg_abc
  from ofsted_items
) t
```

At one point or another you will have to explicitly write out one expression for each column, so `jsonb_to_recordset` doesn't really buy you that much.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=23c2a5d3607277208f90cd62cdaf1f29)

If you need this a lot, you can easily put this into a view.

Comment: smart! this saves me a step

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation to pivot your table. This can be done using the `CASE` clause as it was done at the solution you already linked or using the `FILTER` clause:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a36bda23b5fb104a5f073f28c1bb8961)

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,

    bool_and(true) FILTER (WHERE register = 'xyz') as "register_xyz?",
    MAX(age_from) FILTER (WHERE register = 'xyz') as xyz_age_from,
    MAX(age_to) FILTER (WHERE register = 'xyz') as xyz_age_to,
    MAX(maximum_number) FILTER (WHERE register = 'xyz') as xyz_maximum_number,

    bool_and(true) FILTER (WHERE register = 'abc') as "register_abc?",
    MAX(age_from) FILTER (WHERE register = 'abc') as abc_age_from,
    MAX(age_to) FILTER (WHERE register = 'abc') as abc_age_to,
    MAX(maximum_number) FILTER (WHERE register = 'abc') as abc_maximum_number
FROM items,
    jsonb_to_recordset(items.care_ages) AS care_ages ("age_from" integer, "age_to" integer, "register" text, "maximum_number" integer)
GROUP BY id, name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below query:

```
select id,name,
max(case when register='xyz' then true end) as "register_xyz?",
max(case when register='xyz' then age_from end) as xyz_age_from,
max(case when register='xyz' then age_to end) as xyz_age_to,
max(case when register='xyz' then maximum_number end) as xyz_maximum_number,
max(case when register='abc' then true end) as "register_abc?",
max(case when register='abc' then age_from end) as abc_age_from,
max(case when register='abc' then age_to end) as abc_age_to,
max(case when register='abc' then maximum_number end) as abc_maximum_number

from (SELECT
    items.id,
    items.name,
    care_ages.*

FROM 
    ofsted_items,
    jsonb_to_recordset(items.care_age) AS care_ages ("AgeFrom" integer, "AgeTo" integer, "Register" text, "MaximumNumber" integer)
)t
group by id, name
```